# Get all hash in array, ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Can I get all hash in array like this:

```
a = [[[{id => "1", com => "abcd"}],[{id => "2", com => "rty"},{id => "3", com => "mnq"},...]], "products"]
```

I want to get hash only like this :

```
b = [{id => "1", com => "abcd"},{id => "2", com => "rty"},{id => "3", com => "mnq"},...]
```

Please! tell me how to do that in ruby on rails :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use the `#flatten` or `#flatten!` methods found for Array's in Ruby

So just use

`a.flatten`

and the result will be what is shown in `b`

More information can be found [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten).

Comment: As the last element of `a` is not a hash, it appears you need an additional step: `a.flatten.select { |obj| obj.is_a? Hash }`.